# Alternate logo for Chat room footers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, design, logo

Can we have alternate logos for the Chat rooms? As far as I can tell, these all look ok

1. [Tex](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)
2. [Super user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)
3. [Server fault](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room)
4. [Meta SO](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

These look reasonable, but show some compression artefact

1. [Workplace](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler)
2. [IT security](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz)
3. [Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)
4. [Drupal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2227/drupal-town-hall-chat)

I frequent [The Heap (DBA)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) which could be the most distorted of the lot from the compression to fit in the footer.

<sub><sub>(Is it coincidence that the highest traffic sites have degradable logos. I think not?!)</sub></sub>